# How can I continuously run function after data is appended and function for that data is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Still a newby at JS and jQuery and have what I believe to be a simple fix to a problem I'm having. I have a function I am running after the document is ready, this function is fading in  data then fading out but when it reaches the end of those results nothing else shows up. I just want to loop that function so that those results are constantly being displayed. I probably made that sound a lot more confusing than it needed to be, so here's what I have..

```
    function shuffle(array) {
        var currentIndex = array.length;
        var temporaryValue;
        var randomIndex;
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }
        return array;
    }

    var feedbackContainer = $(".feedback-container");
    var feedbackMessage;

    function getData(data) {

        if (data.ok) {
            var dataResults = shuffle(data.results);
            for (var i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
                feedbackMessage = dataResults[i].message;
                if(feedbackMessage) {
                    var review = $("<p />").text(feedbackMessage);
                    feedbackContainer.append(review);
                }
            };
        }
    }

    $(function(){
        $('.feedback-container p').each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(7000*index).fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly (I'm a little slow on the uptake sometimes), there are a couple simple ways to make a function loop. One being have the function call itself at the end.

```
function foo() {
    // Do a bunch of stuff
    foo();
}
```

or even better, use setInterval so you can have it run only as often as needed.

```
var bar = setInterval(foo, 1000); //runs every second

clearInterval(bar); //when you want it to stop
```

I hope that helps

You can make a loop function that calls your getData and draws repeatedly. So say you setInterval on this function called loop.

```
function loop() {
    getData(); //So you know the data is up to date.
    drawData(); //Your fadeIn/fadeOut script.
    //And if necessary 
    clearData();
}
```

This will loop through retrieving data and displaying it. Does that help?

Comment: What if I wanted an infinite loop so that it's constantly pulling data and fading it in and out. Would I make a call back function once the getData function is complete?

Comment: Made a quick addition. Did that answer your question?